# AWS Redshift - ILIKE doesn't work with accented words

Tags: amazon-redshift

We've been working with AWS Redshift for some time now and recently we faced a quite interesting situation.

Suppose we have the following table.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cities (city VARCHAR(256), state VARCHAR(256));
```

And the following sample data

```sql
INSERT INTO cities (city, state) VALUES 
('Campos do Jordão', 'São Paulo'),
('CAMPOS DO JORDÃO', 'SÃO Paulo'),
('campos do jordão', 'são paulo'),
('Balneário Camburiú', 'Santa Catarina'),
('balneÁrio camburiú', 'Santa Catarina'),
('BALNEÁRIO camburiÚ', 'Santa Catarina'),
('Açailândia', 'Maranhão'),
('AÇailândia', 'Maranhão'),
('AÇAILÂNDIA', 'Maranhão'),
('Salvador', 'Bahia'),
('SALvADOR', 'BAHIA'),
('salVAdor', 'BAHiA')
;
```

We want to filter all rows corresponding to a specific city. Consider that the data hasn't passed through a validating process, so the same city name is written in multiple different ways.

We tried using `ILIKE`, such as `SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city ILIKE 'Campos do Jordão'`, but the result was the following

| city | state |
| --- | --- |
| Campos do Jordão | São Paulo |
| campos do jordão | são paulo |

We got two records instead of three. After some testing we discovered that the problem occurs due to the accented characters (such as `ã`, `ç`, `á`). For example the query

```sql
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city ILIKE '%Ú%';
```

returns only the record `('BALNEÁRIO camburiÚ', 'Santa Catarina')`, while the same query returns the other two records if we replace `%Ú%` by `%ú%`.

I thought this happened because Redshift treated these accented characters as special characters, but it worked as expected initially when we used `UPPER`. For example, the query below returned all three records of `Balneário Camburiú`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE UPPER(city) ILIKE '%Ú%';
```

I'm posting this example here to ask if I'm missing something on the `ILIKE` command or if this is actually some kind of bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_patternmatching_condition_like.html

> LIKE performs a case-sensitive pattern match. ILIKE performs a case-insensitive pattern match for single-byte UTF-8 (ASCII) characters. To perform a case-insensitive pattern match for multibyte characters, use the LOWER function on expression and pattern with a LIKE condition.

I think the problem is coming from that Redshift does not actually understand Unicode.

Redshift stores into a `varchar` whatever bit-patterns you put in there, valid Unicode or not.

When it performs comparisons, it's performing a byte-by-byte comparison, not a character-by-character comparison.

I think there are some *functions* which understand Unicode, such as `upper()` and `lower()` - they're written separately to the main code base.  You have to understand Unicode to change the case of a multi-byte UTF-8 character; but `LIKE` and `ILIKE` do not, they're operators, not functions, so they are from the core database code base, which is *not* Unicode aware.  You have to do some work for them, using the Unicode-aware functions, to allow them to function correctly.

BTW, it was a fascenating question and answer also.  Thankyou for asking.